# How to convert Base64 into HTML using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Here i tried converting the base64 to html using the Mammoth npm, but it is throwing an error: -**
>   throw new Error(“Can’t find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? ” +

Error: Can’t find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html
   at ZipEntries.readEndOfCentral (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:149:23)
   at ZipEntries.load (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:215:14)
   at new ZipEntries (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:21:14)
   at JSZip.module.exports [as load] (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/jszip/lib/load.js:11:18)
   at new JSZip (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/jszip/lib/index.js:39:14)
   at Object.openArrayBuffer (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/mammoth/lib/zipfile.js:10:19)
   at Object.openZip (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/mammoth/lib/unzip.js:16:41)
   at convert (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/mammoth/lib/index.js:34:18)
   at Object.convertToHtml (/Users/Desktop/mommoth/node_modules/mammoth/lib/index.js:22:12)
   at /Users/Desktop/mommoth/server.js:49:10
   at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)

```
let base64String = 'data:text;base64,TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlzIHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2YgdGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGludWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRoZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=';

let base64Path = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();

let buff = new Buffer(base64Path, 'Base64');

console.log(buff);

mammoth.convertToHtml({ buffer :  buff })                
 .then(function(error,result){

    if(error){console.error(error)}

   else{

       console.log('convert');              
       console.log(result);
   }

  })

.done();

});
```

Comment: Are you uploading ZIP file?

Comment: No, i just want to convert the base64 into html and get the result and store in the result variable. but it is somehow creating a zip file when i'm specifying the buffer in the mammoth.convertToHTML.
here  :-- mammoth.convertToHtml({ buffer :  buff3 })

Answer (score 0):

What is your node version?

```
new Buffer(base64Path, 'base64');
```

This method is for Node.js v5.11.1 and below, if your Node.js version is v6.0.0 or above, you should convert in this way

```
let buff = Buffer.from(base64Path, 'base64');
```

Comment: I've node version v8.11.3 ,I tried doing that i keep getting the same error :

Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html

Comment: What is `buff3` ?

Comment: It's a variable i've created for buffer.

Comment: It must be `buff` and after edit it's ok. Are you using sample base64 here for describe your problem or this base64 is your problem?